# Hourglass for iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to exploring iOS application right now. I got a simple idea, which is to create an hourglass application. I did found some apps on the App Store, but the animation is not quite satisfying. Lets say, if I want to create a smooth animation of the sand falling down, the gravity, is there any advice on where should I start? I am thinking to use OpenGL ES for the animation. not sure if this is a good idea, since I do not know how to keep the sand in the hourglass, and each grain falls perfectly fine. is there any algorithm that I should look into?

Comment: have you looked into particle effects, used for smoke and clouds e.t.c

Comment: @geminiCoder didn't know about that before. thanks for pointing it out